# Posting two collections at once with multer

Tags: javascript, post, multer, gridfs

I have a problem with posting two collections - one is file, one is literal object with fields based on file.
Here's the route method

```
// @route POST /upload
// @desc  Uploads file to DB
router.post('/', upload.single('file'), auth, (req, res) => {
  const newFile = new File({
    fileID: req.file.id,
    src: 'api/files/image/' + req.file.filename,
    altText: 'No image',
    caption: req.body.caption
  })
  newFile.save()

});
```

and File model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
// Create Schema
const FileSchema = new Schema({
  fileID: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
  },
  src: {
    type: String
  },
  altText: {
    type: String
  },
  caption: {
    type: String
  }
});

module.exports = File = mongoose.model('file', FileSchema);
```

The problem is, that if I do it that way I can't get caption property and I have errors:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

or if I remove that

> req.file.id

I get

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined

even that I get good values in my database.
If I remove both id and filename I get caption property.
So the problem is there:

```
    fileID: req.file.id,
    src: 'api/files/image/' + req.file.filename
```

but I don't know how to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know how to deal with it, but I did console log in post route method:
// @route POST /upload
// @desc  Uploads file to DB

```
router.post('/', upload.single('file'), auth, (req, res) => {
console.log(req.file);
  const newFile = new File({
    fileID: req.file.id,
    src: 'api/files/image/' + req.file.filename,
    altText: 'No image',
    caption: req.body.caption
  })
  newFile.save()

});
```

and I get:

```
undefined
[0] { fieldname: 'file',
[0]   originalname: 'slide1.jpg',
[0]   encoding: '7bit',
[0]   mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
[0]   id: 5de06f65ff1bdb5388f1a44c,
[0]   filename: 'e872d1cafee8d191b256d27efc5ac94f.jpg',
[0]   metadata: null,
[0]   bucketName: 'files',
[0]   chunkSize: 261120,
[0]   size: 235600,
[0]   md5: '06ef6fba95a331af99276199589d3ed4',
[0]   uploadDate: 2019-11-29T01:07:50.105Z,
[0]   contentType: 'image/jpeg' }
```

So it looks that I have to await for request, because

> req.file

isn't yet defined, so I get error and it stop and don't post this req.body.caption.
That is what I suspect.